# MYSQL GROUP BY 2 field with condition

Tags: mysql, group-by

need help
I have a table:

```
user | visit |.... 
user = 1,2,3,4
visit = 1,2,3,4
```

QUERY will work, but i want to agragate fields in MYSQL

```
SELECT COUNT(visit) as c, t.visit, t.user  FROM t GROUP BY t.visit, t.user
```

I need return GROUP BY user fields without duplicate rows in filed user:

t.user, COUNT (t.visit where t.visit=1), COUNT( all t.visit)

> user = 1 | visit1 = 10|. visit total = 100

......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To conditionally count a column, count the result of a `CASE` expression...

```
SELECT
  t.user,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN t.visit = 1 THEN 1 END)   AS visit_1,
  COUNT(*)   AS visit_total
FROM
  t
GROUP BY
  t.user
```

Notes:

- if a `CASE` expression doesn't have an `ELSE` clause, it defaults to `ELSE NULL`.
- `COUNT()` only counts values that are `NOT NULL`.

Comment: Hi, Could u help me one more time.  IN this query i need else one GROUP BY field3, and i also need agregate MYSQL return by field user.  I need: t.user|count(case visit=1)|COUNT(*)|JSON_ARRAYAGG(field3)

Comment: @АлександрГрешников - Open a new question and I'll keep an eye out for it.